# Does OpenSSH use padding of random lengths?

Tags: network, ssh, random, openssh, side-channel

According to the end of [RFC 4253 § 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6), the random padding introduced to each SSH packet is an arbitrary multiple of 8. It mentions that random padding lengths can mitigate [traffic analysis](https://www.trisul.org/blog/analysing-ssh/post.html):

> Note that the length of the concatenation of 'packet_length', 'padding_length', 'payload', and 'random padding' MUST be a multiple of the cipher block size or 8, whichever is larger.  This constraint MUST be enforced, even when using stream ciphers.  Note that the 'packet_length' field is also encrypted, and processing it requires special care when sending or receiving packets.  *Also note that the insertion of variable amounts of 'random padding' may help thwart traffic analysis.*

Emphasis mine. I am aware that the padding contents themselves are required to be random, but does OpenSSH itself use random padding *lengths* for any cipher modes? The padding length field itself is encrypted for [some modes](http://blog.djm.net.au/2013/11/chacha20-and-poly1305-in-openssh.html). Looking at [the source](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/18813a32b6fd964037e0f5e1893cb4468ac6a758/packet.c#L1223), it doesn't *look* like it uses padding of random lengths, but I am not particularly familiar with the internals of OpenSSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this article](https://www.trisul.org/blog/reverse-ssh/post.html) it does not, but I arrived at this topic seeking confirmation of this article to begin with so take it for what it's worth. The relevant quote from the article is:

> OpenSSH does not implement the “random padding” feature of RFC4253 The secure shell protocol which says " the insertion of variable amounts of ‘random padding’ may help thwart traffic analysis". Until they fix that we can use this technique to detect tunnels.

Comment: This is what I suspected, thanks. I'm surprised that I didn't notice that part of the article.